# Calculate all solutions of non linear congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$, the number $a^{p}-a$ is an integer multiple of $p$. In the notation of modular arithmetic, this is expressed as
$$
a^{p} \equiv a \quad(\bmod p)
$$

Using Little Fermat Theorem: find all solutions:
$x^{14} \equiv 9(\bmod 13)$

I'm having first experience with non linear congruences so i would be glad if somebody explained my how to make progress with that.

Comment: Can you remind us and yourself what Fermat's Little Theorem says?

Comment: So, $x^{13}\equiv x\pmod{13}$, yes?  So rather than looking for solutions to $x^{14}\equiv 9\pmod{13}$ we can instead look for solutions to $x^{13}\cdot x\equiv 9\pmod{13}$ which by FLT is $x\cdot x\equiv 9\pmod{13}$.  Yes?  Can you solve this other simpler problem?

Comment: Substituting $\,x^{13}\equiv x\,$ yields $\,0\equiv x^2-3^2\equiv (x-3)(x+3)\,$ and you solve that as in the dupe.